# Mostrar datos en tabla que probienen de una base de datos

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos

Hola a tod@s tengo creada una tabla en la cual quiero que me muestre los datos que tengo almacenados en una base de datos, me muestra la tabla pero no aparecen los datos. La conexión con la base de datos la hace correctamente, he mirado si los campos eran los correcto y no veo el error. He revisado varias veces el código pero por más vueltas que le doy no lo encuentro. Muestro lo que tengo echo por si veís cual es mí error. Gracias

```
<code>

    <?php

    include "../php/conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();
    ?>

`      `<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2> </h2>
        <caption>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNuevo">
                    Agregar nuevo
                    <span class="fas fa-plus"></span>
                </button>
        </caption>
        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>DESCRIPCION</td>
                <td>UNIDADES</td>
                <td>PRECIO</td>
                <td>TOTAL</td>
                <td>Editar</td>
                <td>Eliminar</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
                $sql="SELECT descripcion,unidades,precio,total from registro";
                $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

                while ($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            ?>          

            <tr>
                <td><?php $ver[1]?></td>
                <td><?php $ver[2]?></td>
                <td><?php $ver[3]?></td>
                <td><?php $ver[4]?></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning far fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion"></button>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger fas fa-trash-alt"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
                }
            ?>
            <!--<tr>

                <td colspan="3" class="font-weight-bold text-right">TOTAL BRUTO</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning far fa-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion"></button>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger fas fa-trash-alt"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>-->
        </table>
</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al parecer veo que tienes algunos pequeños problemas en tu código.
En esta parte de tu código, te falta agregar echo para que se imprima la variable en pantalla.

```
<td><?php $ver[1]?></td>
<td><?php $ver[2]?></td>
<td><?php $ver[3]?></td>
<td><?php $ver[4]?></td>
```

Quedando algo asi:

```
<td><?php echo $ver[1]?></td>
<td><?php echo $ver[2]?></td>
<td><?php echo $ver[3]?></td>
<td><?php echo $ver[4]?></td>
```

Saludos:)

Comment: Muchas gracias era eso, llevo dando vueltas toda la tarde :). Estoy empezando en desarrollo web, siguiendo un curso y por no fijarme bien pues es lo que pasa. Gracias

Comment: Animo con el curso, el normal que se olviden cosas así, yo llevo años y aún me pasa >.<